# Comando GIT para apagar o último log sem afetar a versão atual

Tags: git, versionamento

Gostaria de apagar o último log do commit que realizei, o log do commit que está lá é de uma arquivo que apaguei, porém, não quero que isso fique no versionamento, qual é o comando git que preciso fazer para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ivan**,

**1. Faça uma cópia de segurança (por precaução)**

Agora, para reverter o último commit mas manter as alterações (seu caso):

```
git reset HEAD~
```

Se você não quer que as modificações do último commit se mantenham:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Imagina, por nada! Se a resposta foi útil, marque-a por favor como a resolvida!

Comment: Só vi agora, que não tinha marcado.